# Random number from text seed

Tags: php, random, numbers

I am trying to create a random number from a string seed, this is what I've tried:

```
<?

function rand_n( $text )
{
  return fmod( hexdec( md5( $text ) ), 1000 ) + 1000;
}

for( $i=0; $i<=250; $i++ ) {
    $n = rand_n( "test$i" );
    $a[] = $n;
    echo $n . "\n";
}

echo "Total: " . count( $a ) . "\n";
$a = array_unique( $a );
echo "Unique: " . count( $a ) . "\n";
```

That kinda works but it gives me a lot of duplicates. I tried other methods but they gave me huge numbers and I want to keep it to 4 or 5 number result. I know that with 5 letters one can generate more unique entried than with 5 numbers, but my entries are similar to test0...250 they are not so random.

How can I make this random number generator return unique values depending on the string seed, and keeping the length of the result at 4 or 5?

Comment: Sounds to me like you don't want random numbers at all...you want a hash function for strings that produces a small integer. I'd use something like FNV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base 36 to Integer:

intval($str,36)
Integer to Base 36 (or what ever you want it to be):

base_convert($val, 10, 36)

Answer (score 1):

The decimal value from `md5()` can't be properly represented; instead you can use [`crc32()`](http://php.net/crc32) to give you a 32bit integer value which you can then apply the modulo to:

```
function rand_n( $text )
{
  return crc32($text) % 1000 + 1000;
}
```

It yields 222 / 251 unique values, more than twice as much as the original code.